# Need to get values from MySQL table where certain conditions do NOT exist

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT monthly_returns.company_id
        FROM monthly_returns LEFT JOIN paidreturns ON monthly_returns.company_id = paidreturns.company_id
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM paidreturns WHERE paidreturns.company_id = monthly_returns.company_id
        AND paidreturns.month = '$cdate' and paidreturns.paid = 1)
```

Tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paidreturns` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `paid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `month` date NOT NULL,
  `total` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `monthly_returns` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pay_week1` decimal(9,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_week2` decimal(9,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_week3` decimal(9,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_week4` decimal(9,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_week5` decimal(9,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_weeks` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I am trying to get a list of companies which have not paid a return for this month.
I am using 'NOT EXISTS' to achieve this but I am still getting a company returned which has a return paid for this month.
Any help appreciated...

Comment: Your question is still a little ambiguous, and please provide some sample data of what IS vs what you WANT.  Also, your denormalized data on monthly_returns showing each possible week for a max of 5 for any given month can lead to future problems.  Now back to the question.  Are YOU providing the "Date" in question for the query, or do you want the month of the CURRENT DATE to always be the basis.  Per Soaica's answer, if record doesn't exist for the month, don't return anything... doesn't exist where.. Monthly_Returns, or PaidReturns?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      monthly_returns.company_id 
   FROM 
      monthly_returns 
         LEFT JOIN paidreturns 
            ON monthly_returns.company_id = paidreturns.company_id 
           AND paidreturns.month = '$cdate' 
           and paidreturns.paid = 1 
   WHERE 
      paidreturns.company_id IS NULL
```

Comment: That is working correctly where the users have an entry in the paidreturns table for the selected month. If a record doesn't exist for a selected month it is returning all entries in the paid returns table. This second behavior is not what I need. If a record doesn't exist for the selected month then I don't want anything returned...

Comment: can you add to your question the 2 tables structure?

Comment: Left join returns all entries from the table. Using the suggestions I came up with the following which is giving the result I need:

SELECT DISTINCT monthly_returns.company_id
            FROM monthly_returns, paidreturns
            WHERE monthly_returns.company_id = paidreturns.company_id
            AND paidreturns.month =  '$cdate'
            AND paidreturns.paid = 0"